# Bootstrap not closing menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I maked one html site using bootstrap. That sites have one menu but i think problem is my javascript i maked it that auto open when mouseover it menu but not closed automatic.

```js
     (function($){
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('ul.nav [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('mouseover', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault(); 
       event.stopPropagation(); 
       $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
      });
     });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
    .navbar-brand {display:none;}
    .fullwidth {width:100%; background:#1e537f;}

    .navbar {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
     width:100%;
     text-align:center;
    }

    .navbar-header {}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {color:#FFFFFF;}
    .navbar-inverse
    {background:#1e537f; text-align:center;}

    .navbar-nav>li {text-align:center;}

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {color:#FFFFFF;}

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {background:#143957;}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {background:#143957; border:none;}
    .navbar-nav>a:hover {background:#1b4b72;}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {background:#1b4b72;}
    .navbar ul{text-align:center; padding:0 0 0 30%; }
    .navbar ul li {text-align:left;}
    .navbar ul li ul {padding:0;}

    .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {background:#1b4b72; }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {background:#1b4b72;}
    .dropdown-menu {border:none; }
    .dropdown-menu>li>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        white-space: nowrap;

    }

    .nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover {background:#143957;
    color:#FFFFFF; }

    .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
        display: block;
    background:#143957;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:4px;

    }
    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {background:#1b4b72;}

    .dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:0;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
    .dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
    .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#555;}
    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}
    .carousel-indicators li {width:40px; height:40px;border-radius:50%; background:#FFFFFF;}
    .carousel-indicators .active  {width:40px; height:40px;border-radius:50%; background:#1e537f; border:none;}
    .carousel-caption {margin-bottom:80px;}
    .carousel-caption  h2{ font-size:46px;}
    .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {background:none;}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top marginBottom-0" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">Menu</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                                                             
                        <li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Anasayfa&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>

                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">&nbsp;&nbsp;Kurumsal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="hakkimizda.html">Hakkımızda </a></li>
    <li><a href="cozum-ortaklarimiz.html">Çözüm Ortaklarımız  </a></li>
    <li><a href="sosyal-sorumluluk.html">Sosyal Sorumluluk  </a></li>
    <li><a href="basin-odasi.html">Basın Odası </a></li>
    </ul></li>               
                           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hizmetler <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               
     <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Araç Sigortaları</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="tam-kasko-paket-policesi.html">Tam Kasko Paket Poliçesi </a></li>
        <li><a href="trafik-sigortasi.html">Trafik Sigortası </a></li>
     <li><a href="yesil-kart-sigortasi.html">Yeşil Kart Sigortası  </a></li>
    </ul></li>

    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">İşyeri ve Konut Sigortaları</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="isyeri-paket-sigortalari.html">İşyeri Paket Sigortaları </a></li>
        <li><a href="konut-paket-sigortalari.html">Konut Paket Sigortaları </a></li>
     <li><a href="dask-sigortasi.html">Dask Sigortası </a></li>
    </ul></li>

    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sorumluluk Sigortaları  </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="ucuncu-sahis-mali-sorumluluk.html">Üçüncü Şahıs Mali Sorumluluk </a></li>
        <li><a href="asansor-sorumluluk.html">Asansör Sorumluluk</a></li>
     <li><a href="isveren-sorumluluk.html">İşveren Sorumluluk</a></li>
      <li><a href="mesleki-sorumluluk.html">Mesleki Sorumluluk</a></li>
        <li><a href="zorunlu-hekim-sigortasi.html">Zorunlu Hekim Sigortası</a></li>
      <li><a href="ferdi-kaza-sigortasi.html">Ferdi Kaza Sigortası</a></li>
        <li><a href="tasinan-para-sigortasi.html">Taşınan Para Sigortası</a></li>
      <li><a href="emniyeti-suistimal-sigortasi.html">Emniyeti Suistimal Sigortası</a></li>
        <li><a href="urun-mali-sorumluluk-sigortasi.html">Ürün Mali Sorumluluk Sigortası</a></li>
        <li><a href="seyahat-sigortasi.html">Seyahat Sigortası</a></li>
        </ul></li>
             
             
             <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Nakliyat Sigortaları  </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="mal-nakli-sigortalari.html">Mal Nakli Sigortaları </a></li>
        <li><a href="nakliyat-sorumluluk-sigortalari.html">Nakliyat Sorumluluk Sigortaları</a></li>
     <li><a href="deniz-araclari-sigortasi.html">Deniz Araçları Sigortası </a></li>
        </ul></li>                
                          
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mühendislik Sigortaları </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="elektronik-cihaz-sigortasi.html">Elektronik Cihaz Sigortası </a></li>
        <li><a href="makina-kirilmasi-sigortasi.html">Makina Kırılması Sigortası</a></li>
     <li><a href="insaat-sigortasi.html">İnşaat Sigortası</a></li>
    </ul></li>

                          
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sağlık Sigortaları </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="saglik-sigortasi.html">Sağlık Sigortası </a></li>
        <li><a href="tamamlayici-saglik-sigortasi.html">Tamamlayıcı Sağlık Sigortası</a></li>

    </ul></li>
    </ul>
                        </li>                   
                       <li><a href="servisler.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Servisler&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a></li>
                        <li><a href="kariyer.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Kariyer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li> 
                         <li><a href="iletisim.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;İletişim&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li> 
        </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
```

You can test my code it is on up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to create a mouseenter function for the dropdown toggle and then a mouseleave function for the dropdown and dropdown-submenu.  If im understanding your problem correctly.  So your code should look something like this I think.

```
 $('ul.nav [data-toggle=dropdown').on({
  mouseenter: function(event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    }
  }
});
$('ul.nav .dropdown, .dropdown-submenu').on({
  mouseleave: function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a link to a fiddle with it working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/3sxcx4vv/).

Just to let you know you may run into some problems with your menu being too long because when the mouse leaves the dropdown menu and submenus the menu will close so they will not be able to scroll down to see all of the links but if I understand your problem correctly I think this should solve your problem.

P.S I left the event in there in case you need an event to be executed but if not you can take it out.

Comment: Thank you so much your perfect answer and advice :)